# Proper way to link to Caffe library

Tags: c++, cmake, caffe

I am using [caffe library](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) for my project.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is as follow

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(endtoendlib)
set(Caffe_DIR "/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/build/cmake")
include_directories( ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

# Find Caffe
FIND_PACKAGE(Caffe REQUIRED)
# adding sources to target
add_executable(endtoendlib endtoendLstm.cpp)
target_link_libraries(endtoendlib ${Caffe_LIBS})
```

When I run `cmake ..` , I have error as

```
CMake Warning (dev) at
 /home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/build/cmake/CaffeConfig.cmake:22
 (if):
   given arguments:

     "ON"

   An argument named "ON" appears in a conditional statement.  Policy CMP0012
   is not set: if() recognizes numbers and boolean constants.  Run "cmake
   --help-policy CMP0012" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
   set the policy and suppress this warning.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMakeLists.txt:9 (FIND_PACKAGE)
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

How can I solve the problem?

Is there a better way to link to caffe library and its accessories?

Comment: Read the whole message, especially the part at the end that say "This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it." In short, it's a problem for the Caffe developers and not for you. Your `CMakeLists.txt` file should work fine. Either live with it, silence it with `-Wno-dev` or report it to the Caffe developers and hope they fix it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude,  No it doesn't  work. Whenever I configure, it always goes to this message. How can I use -Wno-dev to supress this warning?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "it doesn't work" part? *How* doesn't it work? Do you get more errors or warnings when running `cmake`? Do you get build errors? And how did you download and *build* Caffe? What version? The name `caffe-master` in the path seems to indicate that you're working on a Git checkout of the master branch, instead of relying on an actual released version. Have you tried installing a release instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I put a line cmake_policy(SET CMP0012 OLD) into my cmake file and no more such warning. Thanks

Comment: Its a bug in your software, some variable seems to be used in the wrong manner. Update to the latest version, maybe from Git. If that does not help, as the developers.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have difficulty to link to caffe library from your c++ project using cmake, the following is the CMakeLists.txt I could successfully used. Please change to the correct path according to your setting.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0012 OLD)

PROJECT(endtoendlib)


if(ON)
  if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
    set(Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH "/usr/local/share/OpenCV")
    if(Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH)
      get_filename_component(Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH ${Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH} ABSOLUTE)

      if(EXISTS ${Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH} AND NOT TARGET opencv_core)
        message(STATUS "Caffe: using OpenCV config from ${Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH}")
        include(${Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH}/OpenCVModules.cmake)
      endif()

    else()
      find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
    endif()
    unset(Caffe_OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH)
  endif()
endif()

# Compute paths
get_filename_component(Caffe_CMAKE_DIR "/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/build/cmake" PATH)
set(Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/include")
list(APPEND Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include")
list(APPEND Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include")
list(APPEND Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/include/opencv")
list(APPEND Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/atlas")
list(APPEND Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/build/src/")

# Our library dependencies
#if(NOT TARGET caffe AND NOT caffe_BINARY_DIR)
include("/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/build/ccmake/CaffeTargets.cmake")
#endif()

# List of IMPORTED libs created by CaffeTargets.cmake
set(Caffe_LIBRARIES "/home/Softwares/Libraries/caffe-master/build/lib/libcaffe.so")

# Definitions
set(Caffe_DEFINITIONS "-DUSE_OPENCV;-DUSE_LMDB;-DUSE_LEVELDB")

# Cuda support variables
set(Caffe_CPU_ONLY OFF)
set(Caffe_HAVE_CUDA TRUE)
set(Caffe_HAVE_CUDNN FALSE)


include_directories( ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} ${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# adding sources to target
add_executable(endtoendlib endtoendLstm.cpp)
target_link_libraries(endtoendlib ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Caffe_LIBRARIES} -lglog -lprotobuf -lboost_system)
```

If you have error like follow, that means you didn't build caffe with `WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1 in Makefile.config`

```
Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type: ImageData (known types: AbsVal, Accuracy, ArgMax, BNLL, BatchNorm, BatchReindex, Bias, Concat, ContrastiveLoss, Convolution, Crop, Data, Deconvolution, Dropout, DummyData, ELU, Eltwise, Embed, EuclideanLoss, Exp, Filter, Flatten, HDF5Data, HDF5Output, HingeLoss, Im2col, InfogainLoss, InnerProduct, Input, LRN, LSTM, LSTMUnit, Log, MVN, MemoryData, MultinomialLogisticLoss, PReLU, Parameter, Pooling, Power, RNN, ReLU, Reduction, Reshape, SPP, Scale, Sigmoid, SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss, Silence, Slice, Softmax, SoftmaxWithLoss, Split, TanH, Threshold, Tile)
```